# Display html tags in angular template, don't render it

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to write some information about html tags in angular app. I am not able to figure how to display html tags in inside angular template without rendering html.

e.g.

`component.html`

```
 <p> you can use <code> </p> </code> tag for paragraph </p>
```

Expected :

`you can use </p> tag for paragraph`

One way is to create variable in component and interpolate it in view. But I don't think to create so many variables only for single tag text.

e.g.
`component.html`

```
 <p> you can use <code> {{myPTag}} </code> tag for paragraph </p>
```

`component.ts`

```
... 
myPTag = "</p>"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use '<' or '>' instead use `&lt;` and `&gt;`